# How to add value to Drupal Commerce 2 order information form?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-commerce

I am created a Drupal module and added the form alter function:

```
    MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
     if(($form_id === 'commerce_checkout_flow_multistep_default') &&
     ($form['#step_id'] === 'order_information')){

      $form['contact_information']['email']['#value'] = $email; // This is working

      ...
```

I also added this code:

```
$form['payment_information']['billing_information']['address'][0]['address']['given_name']['#value'] = $ime;
$form['payment_information']['billing_information']['address'][0]['address']['family_name']['#value'] = $prezime;
$form['payment_information']['billing_information']['address'][0]['address']['address_line1']['#value'] = $adresa;
$form['payment_information']['billing_information']['address'][0]['address']['postal_code']['#value'] = $ptt;
$form['payment_information']['billing_information']['address'][0]['address']['locality']['#value'] = $grad;
```

but this don't work for me. Any idea?

Comment: What does not work exactly ? Are $grad, $prezime, etc.. variables or  strings ? PHP won't expand simple quoted variables like `'$grad'`. Don't quote variables unless it is really necessary and in this case use double quotes. Secondly, `#value` is used to set values that cannot be edited by the user, is this really what you want here ?

Comment: I want to get data from commerce checkout form, and I want to set default value if user is authenticated. These are strings, and I use without ' ', I was wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not expand simple quoted variables like `'$grad'`. Don't quote variables unless it is really necessary and in this case use double quotes : `"$grad"`. See [PHP strings and variable expansion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Secondly, `#value` is used to set values that cannot be edited by the user. Use `#default_value` instead. See [Drupal Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#value)